# How to Publish Web api project - vs 2015

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I published a `webapi` project in vs 2015 and this is the only items in the folder

[image]

Original Folder before publish:
[image]

Comment: And that's exactly what you need. Place those files of the top image on a webserver like IIS and than after setting IIS up correctly it should work. All your DLLs will be in the bin folder.

Comment: I am using a shared host.